# Count distinct ids in a rolling time frame group by category in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the below structure.  I'm attempting to do a rolling 12 month unique count of Employeesid's by Team.  I feel like one of my problem is the fact that I have Year and Month in a separate column? But any idea on how to do this in r using dplyr and lubridate.

My current code only calculates the unique employees by team, year, month how do I add in the rolling 12 month?

I've provided an example data and expected results.

Dataframe1

```
Team    Employeesid     YYYY_MM_DD  Year    Month
Susan   34  2014-01-01  2014    1
Susan   45  2014-01-01  2014    1
Susan   34  2014-02-01  2014    2
Susan   45  2014-02-01  2014    2
Susan   65  2014-02-01  2014    2
Blake   4   2014-01-01  2014    1
Blake   65  2014-01-01  2014    1
Blake   77  2014-02-01  2014    2
Blake   51  2014-02-01  2014    2
Blake   65  2014-02-01  2014    2
```

Note: I have over 150 teams and # of Employeesid can vary, and each Team has data from 2014 - 2018 (I just did not include in the sample data.

I've also added a date column YYYY_MM_DD by combining my year+month+"01" to get a date column to do -12 months, but it's not working either?

See code:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%  
 dplyr::filter(YYYY_MM_DD - months(12),YYYY_MM_DD)%>%  
  group_by(team,Year,Month) %>% 
  summarise(rolling_12m_emp = n_distinct(Employeesid))
```

Expected results Dataframe2

```
Team     Year Month  rolling_12m_emp
Susan    2014  1       2
Susan    2014  2       3
Blake    2014  1       2
Blake    2014  2       4
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you share the data like this: `dput(df1)` or `dput(head(df1))` if you have large data. copy the outputs of that function to your question

Comment: @mike  I'm new, I'm not sure how I can share my output?  Do I just type in dput(df1) in R?

Comment: Yes once you do that it will output the structure of your data. You can then copy that and put it into your question so people can work with your data. if the data is too large you can always subset your original data and share enough to reproduce your issue.